# How to get the IP and Port number from bluemix?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud

I want to use Server IP address and Port number for one of my applications. but I am unable to find `Bluemix` server IP and Port number where JAVA application is hosted.

Comment: can we know what all you tried to get IP address and port number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server ip address and port will change each time you restart or restage your application. To access the server ip address and port your app instance is currently using you can look up the folowing system properties from your java application:

- VCAP_APP_HOST
- VCAP_PORT